# Trying to print a linked list in c++ recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I've been trying to create an ordered double linked list and then print it out forwards and backwards using recursion. I don't know if I'm adding nodes to the linked list incorrectly or if my problem is in my print functions.

Main

```
int main() {
    ifstream addData;
    addData.open("proj1adds.data");
    LinkedList<int> List;
    Node<int> *head = NULL:
    int add;
    int i = 0;
    while (!addData.eof()){
        addData >> add;
        List.add(i, add);
        i++;
    }
}
```

this is my add function

```
template < typename T >
void LinkedList < T >::add(int index, T element)
{
  if (index == 0){
    addFirst(element);
  }
  else if (index >= size){
    addLast(element);
  }
  else
  {
    Node < T > * current = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++)
      current = current->next;
    Node < T > * temp = current->next;
    current->next = new Node < T > (element);
    (current->next)->prev = current;
    (current->next)->next = temp;
    size++;
  }
}
```

And these are my print functions

```
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::printForward(Node<T> *head){
    if(head==NULL){
        return;
    }
    cout << head->element << endl;
    printForward(head->next);
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::printBackward(Node<T> *head){
    if(head==NULL){
        return;
    }
    printBackward(head->next);
    cout << head->element << endl;
}
```

I think that I've loaded the data into the nodes, but I'm not sure if its ordered because I cant print it.

Comment: At least print backward looks as if it’s going in the wrong direction.  We can’t compile or test your code without the missing pieces of the program, but: what output are you getting? Try single-stepping through the program in a debugger and examining head, *(head->next), etc. Test your if stream to see whether it read anything successfully. That will at least tell you if your data got stored.

Comment: Instead of trying to read data from a file, hard-code a couple of values. Then try printing the contents of *one node*, before attempting recursion. Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, and **never add to code that doesn't work**.

Comment: The data is getting stored I went through the add function line by and line checked it. When I call printFowards(head) or printBackwards(head) in my main it get to the return in the if statement then the run fails. I commented out the exit condition to see what would happen (i expected it to go into an infinite loop) but the run failed as soon as it got to cout << head->element << endl;

Comment: *I don't know if I'm adding nodes to the linked list incorrectly* And neither will anyone else since we don't know what `addFirst` and `addLast` consist of.  Even having separate functions for this looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment (but not in your question) you say that you're calling `printFowards(head)` and `printBackwards(head)` in `main()`. But in `main()`, the variable `head` is a local variable that is set to `NULL`. So the functions abort, and when you comment out the exit condition [*shudder*] you dereference a null pointer and get Undefined Behavior.

Maybe the list *is* being constructed correctly; it doesn't matter because your calls to the printing functions have no connection to the list.